# fontspec kernel/property-unknown

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I have a problem with fontspec. When i try to build simple document:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
   aaa
\end{document}
```

I get an error:

```
P:\Dokumenty\Szablony\xelatex_test>xelatex.exe  document.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(P:\Dokumenty\Szablony\xelatex_test\document.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, arabic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, ngerman-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usenglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls" Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"))
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"))
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3unicode-data.def")
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def"))
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty")
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-patches.sty"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fixltx2e.sty"))
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def")
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"))
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"))
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("P:\Programy\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def"))))

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown"
!
! The key property '.choice_code:n' is unknown.
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.1173  }

? H
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a coding error.
|
| LaTeX has been asked to set the property '.choice_code:n' for key
| 'fontspec-renderer/Renderer': this property is not defined.
|...............................................
?

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown"
!
! The key property '.generate_choices:n' is unknown.
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.1173  }

?
! Emergency stop.
!...............................................

l.1173  }

No pages of output.
Transcript written on document.log.

P:\Dokumenty\Szablony\xelatex_test>
```

This is a fresh installation of MiKTeX

**[EDIT]**

For those who have a similar problem - update all packages helped.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's strange that `fontspec` loads `fixltx2e`, as the more recent version doesn't. I think you have to run the package updater.

Comment: Does that code really produce that output? Since when does `fontspec` or `article` load `graphicx`?! That seems rather unlikely....

Comment: There was a problem very recently with MiKTeX  fontspec, and it was fixed on 07/22 (version 2.4 d), so you should update it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a software bug and has been resolved by updating the TeX installation.

Comment: @cfr — fontspec loads xunicode which loads graphicx for some reflected symbols. We would like to reduce this dependency...

Comment: @WillRobertson Thanks. I didn't know that. (I checked it didn't load it directly.)

Comment: I updated all of my packages to the ftp://math.purdue.edu repository and I still get this error.

Comment: @egreg, I have just gotten a virgin installation of MikTeX and got this error the first time I tried to run XeLaTeX.  Still not working a week later.  I will try to synchronize packages...

Comment: @egreg All packages are updated.  Error persists.

Comment: @Bernard I am having this problem on a virgin MikTeX installation.  I used MikTeX's update wizard to update all packages.  However, I note that it is using a `fontspec` dated `2014/06/21 v2.4a`, whereas your comment seems to indicate something is newer.  Any ideas on why MikTeX does not find it?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have `fontspec 2015/09/24 v2.4e ` (on TeX Live). Possibly a problem between “administrator” and “user” update? I'm no expert in MiKTeX, so I can't help you more than this.

Comment: @egreg Thanks.  At least I am honing in on where the problem is.  I see Will R. is the maintainer.  I will query him.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes What could he say? If you have an old version of `fontspec`, you just need to update. If MiKTeX doesn't do it, it's MiKTeX's fault and the maintainer can do nothing about it.

Comment: @egreg you are wise in the ways of science, Brother Maynard (hat tip Monty Python).  Perhaps I'll contact MikTeX folks.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: I can confirm I have `fontspec v2.4e,2015/9/29`. As @egreg suggested, I would  update both as administrator and as user if needed. You can check  which versions are installed in both cases from  `MiKTeX Package Manager`  (right-click on package name, then select `Properties`).

Comment: @Bernard That is fascinating.  The package manager reports v2.4e is installed, and yet the log file from this question's MWE reports V2.4a is being used.  I guess I need to look why that might be.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes — apologies, I'm baffled as well

Comment: @WillRobertson Freshman mistake.  I had a stray copy of old `fontspec` lying around in my working directory (which had been copied and pasted onto my new machine).

Comment: @Bernard See above comment. I feel stupid.

Comment: @egreg Mea culpa.  See above comments.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Glad to hear it was an easy fix!

Comment: I know this is closed, but i found out that updating user and updating admin is not the same, i did both and resolved the issue for me.